# The page isn't redirecting properly, This webpage has a redirect loop htaccess php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have redirect loop in when I select a category of posts below is my htaccess file:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.rswebtek\.in
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rswebtek.in/$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?CategoryId=$1&Page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?CategoryId=$1 [L]

#Redirect search results
RewriteRule ^search-results/find-(.*)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&Page=$2[L]
RewriteRule ^search-results/find-?(.*)//?$ index.php?SearchResults&SearchString=$1&Page=1 [L]


#Redirect  tag search results
RewriteRule ^tagged/([^/]+)/page-(\d+)/?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^tagged/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?TagSearchResults&TagName=$1&Page=1 [L,QSA]

#Redirect static pages based on page name
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?StaticPage&PageName=$1 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]

# Rewrite Post details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?PostId=$1 [L]
</IfModule> 

# Set the default 500 page for Apache errors
ErrorDocument 500 /rswebtek_blog/500.php

#Set the defualt 404 error page
ErrorDocument 404 /rswebtek_blog/404.php
```

**here is my link.php file:-**

```
<?php
  class Link{
      public static function Build($link, $type='http'){
          $base = (($type == 'http' ||  USE_SSL == 'no') ? 'http://' :'https://').getenv('SERVER_NAME');
          //if HTTP_SERVER_PORT is defined and different than default
          if(defined('HTTP_SERVER_PORT') && HTTP_SERVER_PORT !='80' && strpos($base, 'https') === false){
              //append server port
              $base .=':' . HTTP_SERVER_PORT;
          }
          $link = $base . VIRTUAL_LOCATION . $link;
          //escape html
          return htmlspecialchars($link, ENT_QUOTES);
      }


      public static function ToCategory($categoryId, $page =1){
        $link = self::CleanUrlText(Blog::GetPostCategoryName($categoryId)).
                    '-c'.$categoryId.'/';
      //$link ='index.php?CategoryId='.$categoryId;
          if($page > 1)
            $link .='page-'.$page.'/';
            //$link .= '&Page='.$page;
          return self::Build($link);
      }
      public static function ToPost($postId){
         $link = self::CleanUrlText(Blog::GetPostTitle($postId)).
                   '-p'.$postId.'/';
         // return self::Build('index.php?PostId='.$postId);
          return self::Build($link);

      }
      public static function ToIndex($page = 1){
          $link ='';
          if($page > 1)
              $link .='page-'.$page.'/';
              //$link .='index.php?Page='.$page;
              return self::Build($link);

      }
      public static function QueryStringToArray($queryString){
          $result = array();
          if($queryString !=''){
              $elements =explode('&',$queryString);
              foreach($elements as $key => $value){
                  $element = explode('=',$value);
                  $result[urldecode($element[0])] = isset($element[1]) ? urldecode($element[1]) : '' ;
              }
          }
       return $result;
      }

        // Prepares a string to be included in an URL
        public static function CleanUrlText($string)
        {
        // Remove all characters that aren't a-z, 0-9, dash, underscore or space
        $not_acceptable_characters_regex = '#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]#';
        $string = preg_replace($not_acceptable_characters_regex, '', $string);
        // Remove all leading and trailing spaces
        $string = trim($string);
        // Change all dashes, underscores and spaces to dashes
        $string = preg_replace('#[-_ ]+#', '-', $string);
        // Return the modified string
        return strtolower($string);
        }

             //redirects to proper url if not already there
    public static function CheckRequest(){
        $proper_url = '';
        if (isset ($_GET['Search']) || isset($_GET['SearchResults']) || isset($_GET['TagSearchResults']) || isset($_GET['StaticPage'])){
            return;
        }
    // Obtain proper URL for category pages
    elseif (isset ($_GET['CategoryId'])){
        if (isset ($_GET['Page']))
            $proper_url = self::ToCategory($_GET['CategoryId'], $_GET['Page']);
        else
            $proper_url = self::ToCategory($_GET['CategoryId']);
    }

    // Obtain proper URL for post pages
    elseif (isset ($_GET['PostId'])){
        $proper_url = self::ToPost($_GET['PostId']);
    }
    // Obtain proper URL for the home page
    else{
        if (isset($_GET['Page']))
            $proper_url = self::ToIndex($_GET['Page']);
        else
            $proper_url = self::ToIndex();
    }
    /* Remove the virtual location from the requested URL
    so we can compare paths */
    $requested_url = self::Build(str_replace(VIRTUAL_LOCATION, '',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    //404 redirect if the requested product, category or department 
    //donnot exist
    if(strstr($proper_url, '/-')){
        //clean output buffer
        ob_clean();
        //load the 404 page
        include('404.php');
        //clear the output buffer an stop executon
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        exit();
    }


    // 301 redirect to the proper URL if necessary
    if ($requested_url != $proper_url){
        // Clean output buffer
        ob_clean();
        // Redirect 301
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location:'.$proper_url);
        // Clear the output buffer and stop execution
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        ob_end_clean();
        exit();
    }
   }                                 
   //create link to the search page
   public static function ToSearch(){
       return self::Build('index.php?Search');
   }

    public static function ToSearchResults($searchString, $page = 1){
       $link = 'search-results/find';
       if(empty($searchString))
        $link .='/';
       else
        $link .= '-' . self::CleanUrlText($searchString) . '/';
     // $link .='all-words-'.$allWords.'/';
       if($page > 1)
        $link .= 'page-'.$page.'/';
       return self::Build($link);
   }


   //build tag links 
   public static function  ToTagLinks($tags, $page = 1){   


             $tags = explode(',', $tags); 


             foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
                 $link ='tagged/'.self::CleanUrlText($tag) ;

                 if($page > 1)
                    $link .='/page-'.$page.'/';

                 $tag = '<a class="taglist" href="'.self::Build($link).'" title="">'.$tag.'</a>';
             }
             return  implode(', ', $tags);

   }

    public static function ToStaticPage($pageName){
        //$link ='index.php?StaticPage&PageName='.$pageName;
        $link ='pages/'.self::CleanUrlText($pageName) ;
        return self::Build($link);

    }  

   public static function ToTagNexPreLink($tag, $page = 1){
       $link ='tagged/'.self::CleanUrlText($tag) ;
       if($page > 1)
         $link .='/page-'.$page.'/';
       return self::Build($link);
   }
  ?>
```

**and index.php**

```
<?php
  //active session
  session_start();
  //start output buffer
  ob_start();

  //include utility files
  require_once('include/config.php');
  require_once(BUSINESS_DIR.'error_handler.php');
  //set error handler
  ErrorHandler::SetHandler();




  // Load the database handler
  require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'database_handler.php';
  // Load Business Tier
  require_once BUSINESS_DIR . 'blog.php';

  //Link::CheckRequest();
    // Load presentation Tier

  require_once(PRESENTATION_DIR.'application.php');
  require_once(PRESENTATION_DIR.'link.php');
  Link::CheckRequest();
  $application = new Application();
    //this is used to mute errors
  $application->muteExpectedErrors();


  //display page
  $application->display('blog_front.tpl');
  // close the connection
  DatabaseHandler::Close();
  //output content from the buffer
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

problem arised when I select a category or post :- my static link as follow

http://www.rswebtek.in/database-c3/

any help must be appreciated

Comment: ok from your question it is not clear how `http://www.rswebtek.in/database-c2/` is becoming `http://www.rswebtek.in/programming-languages-c2/`. I can only help you with rewrite rules but you seem to be having some code issues.

Comment: Sir when I used my dyanamic url like http://www.rswebtek.in?Category_id=3 than its work fine but after change it with htaccess then it does not work

Comment: database, programming languages, general are names of my blog post categories Sir

Comment: As I said I can only help you with rewrite rules as I don't know the code. Seems like your code is also affecting rewrites which I cannot fix.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your kind support Sir.